# Can't figure out urllib code syntax in Python 3.9 that worked as urllib2 in Python 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

I am a BASH/PERL/Ansible coder that is not very experienced with Python.  The experience I do have is with Python 2.

I have a piece of code that worked fine in Python2 with urllib2 that I can't figure out how to convert to work in Python 3.9 with urllib.parse and urllib.request from the new urllib now that urllib2 has been deprecated.

The code worked fine with "import urllib2" in Python 2.  I will spare you all of my attempts to get it working in Python 3.9, but I have gotten a plethora of errors including, but not limited to: "*TypeError: POST data should be bytes, an iterable of bytes, or a file object. It cannot be of type str.*", "*TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object*", "*TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'*", "*TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable*", etc.  When I do get the code to run, I get "*urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error*" where as the results come back just fine in Python 2 (and with cURL).  Original code segment below (this works in Python 2 with urllib2):

```
    def linux_inventoryAWS(self):
        servers = []

        data = urllib.urlencode({'header':'yes',
                'query':'select distinct lower(a.name), a.service_level from view_device_v1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN view_device_custom_fields_flat_v1 b ON (a.device_pk=b.device_fk) LEFT JOIN view_objectcategory_v1 cat ON a.objectcategory_fk=cat.objectcategory_pk where a.os_name ~ \'Linux\' and a.in_service=\'t\' and a.type=\'virtual\' and (virtual_subtype=\'Amazon EC2 Instance\' or virtual_subtype=\'Citrix/Xen\' or virtual_subtype=\'Xen\') and (excludefromautmninventory is null or excludefromautmninventory != \'Yes\') order by a.service_level asc'})

        credentials = self.d42_user + ":" + self.d42_pwd
        base64string = base64.b64encode(credentials)
        url = self.d42_url + "/services/data/v1.0/query/"
        request = urllib2.Request(url)
        request.add_header("Authorization", "Basic %s" % base64string)
        request.add_data(data) # "add_data" has also been depreciated and seems to have been replaced by just "data" -- this may be part of the problem with getting 500 errors.
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        ctx.check_hostname = False
        ctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
        result = urllib2.urlopen(request, context=ctx)
        for line in result:
            servers.append(line.strip('\n'))
        result.close()
        servers.pop(0)
        serversAsString = ",".join(servers)
        return servers
```

Comment: I suggest you use `request` instead of `urllib`. It's higher level and handles all the encoding for you.

Comment: I'm afraid that this is beyond my Python knowledge.  I didn't even write the Python 2 code that worked.  I don't want to reinvent the wheel anyway.  Everything I've researched says that this should be doable by simply replacing urllib2.urlencode with urllib.parse.urlencode, urllib2.urlopen with urllib.request.urlopen, and urllib2.Request with urllib.request.Request.  The issue seems to be one of Type.  The new urllib calls seems to not like 'str'.

Comment: An important difference between Python 2 and 3 is that in 2 `str` is a byte sequence (well, actually the type of a byte sequence) and `unicode` is a Unicode string while in 3 `bytes` is a byte sequence and `str` is a Unicode string.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to suggestions from the good people of r/learnpython on Reddit and a lot of trial-and-error, I was able to piece together some code that works in both Python 2 and Python 3.  It uses "requests" instead of either "urllib" or "urllib2".  Code snippet follows:

```
def linux_inventory(self):
    servers = []

    data = {'header':'yes',
            'query':'select distinct lower(a.name), a.service_level from view_device_v1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN view_device_custom_fields_flat_v1 b ON (a.device_pk=b.device_fk) LEFT JOIN view_objectcategory_v1 cat ON a.objectcategory_fk=cat.objectcategory_pk where a.os_name ~ \'Windows\' and a.in_service=\'t\' and a.type=\'virtual\' and (virtual_subtype=\'Amazon EC2 Instance\' or virtual_subtype=\'Citrix/Xen\' or virtual_subtype=\'Xen\') and (excludefromautmninventory is null or excludefromautmninventory != \'Yes\') order by a.service_level asc'}

    if sys.version_info.major == 2:
        credentials = self.d42_user + ":" + self.d42_pwd
    else:
        credentials = bytes(self.d42_user + ":" + self.d42_pwd, 'utf-8')
    base64string = base64.b64encode(credentials)
    url = self.d42_url + "/services/data/v1.0/query/"
    headers = {'Authorization': b'Basic ' + base64string}
    result = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=data)
    for line in result.text.splitlines():
        servers.append(line)
    result.close()
    servers.pop(0)
    serversAsString = ",".join(servers)
    return servers
```